# How to target an id inside of a div class when I hover a different parent div class with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So as the question says, I am trying to hover the class button1 and get the id of 'css'. With my current code, all I get is the id html. I need to get a unique id that's pertinent to which button I hover. I'm still newer to jquery and javascript in general but I can't seem to find any information on this topic so any reference source would be great too if possible.

Here's my code:

### **HTML**

```
<div class="button1">       
     <div class="text">
          <p>Skill<br /> <span class="Score" id = "html">10/10 </span> </p>
     </div>

     <div class="button1 Overlay">
     </div>
<div class="button1">       
     <div class="text">
          <p>Skill<br /> <span class="Score" id = "css">9/10 </span> </p>
     </div>

     <div class="button1 Overlay">
     </div>
</div>
```

### **Jquery**

```
('.button1').mouseover(function(event) {
    $(".text").attr('id');
})
```

Comment: PS: typo `('.button1')` is invalid jQuery - Should be `$('.button1')`

Comment: PS, may I know what are you actually trying to achieve? I highly suspect you need any JS at all.

Comment: And as an off-topic suggestion, if you're creating your own portfolio, even if you've seen it elsewhere, **never** (and I mean it) set your skills in "*N/out-of/N*". Mostly because the latter *N* is highly subjective. Just say you're a Junior, Mid, Senior, or Enthusiast developer, and list the technologies you're proficient with, and list the technologies you'd really like to learn in the near future. *N/N* means nothing. Specially not to a recruiter or to your future employer.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah that's a good point. I'm trying to relate the overlay height to the score so that on hover it shows that along with some other things. I'm thinking about color coding the overlay and having a key that depicts the color with proficiency level. even if it doesn't require js, its good practice for me.  So this is a simplified version of the end goal. It's still got some more time in development, but I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current code you get nothing, since `.text` does not have ID and result is never used. Use `$(this).find('.Score').attr('id')`[[1]](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Note few bug fixes:

1. `('.button1').mouseover` is missing `$`
2. You have nested `.button1` (first one is not properly closed, use proper indentation for easier debugging), so it's impossible to find singe element, because you hover on top most element

```js
$('.button1').mouseover(function(event) {
  console.log($(this).find('.Score').attr('id'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button1">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Skill<br /> <span class="Score" id="html">10/10 </span> </p>
  </div>

  <div class="button1 Overlay">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button1">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Skill<br /> <span class="Score" id="css">9/10 </span> </p>
  </div>

  <div class="button1 Overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good catch on the HTML structure